# Foursquare explore API returning different result than in foursquare app

Tags: foursquare

this is sample explore url :

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=31.4658656,74.3844226&radius=800&limit=30&sortByDistance=1&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20130911&locale=en

venue return from this api is different from venues in foursquare app for same coordinates.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. Seriously though, *what information does it return* and *what do you expect it to return*? Even better, *highlight the difference* between the two outputs for your readers.

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is Userless access. foursquare app uses `oauth_token` instead of `client_id/client_secret`.

ex)
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=40.7,-74&oauth_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN&v=20150824

This is why your URL return different result than in foursquare app.

To use oauth_token, you need to authenticate the user.

Document:
https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#access